# Dual Booting Windows while Hibernated

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, multi-boot, hibernate

Windows 7 and Windows 8 are both installed on my PC, on different partitions of the same hard drive. Whenever I boot the system, I am taken to a screen where I may choose which of the two to boot. If I hibernate one of the OSes and try to reboot, it skips this screen, and automatically boots the OS that is hibernated.

I need to be able to switch between the two OSes quickly while saving my session. Is it possible to boot an OS while the other is hibernated?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.

The only way to do it would be taking out the hibernated HDD. In this case the other Windows boots normally.

Comment: They're both installed on the same hard drive. Is it possible to edit the Windows Boot Manager to ignore the hibernated status of an OS?

Comment: no this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is neither possible nor safe to do, one begets the other.

When you hibernate the system it stores all important information regarding user and system programs running and this will inevitably include filesystem state information as that held by the filesystem drivers.

There may well even be changes pending to be written to the disk that could potentially be suspended during hibernation (though I'd hope not).

That would mean any changes happening to any other disk while the system is hibernated could cause a large amount of instability and a force you to reboot anyway.  Back to square 1, you might as well have already rebooted between needing to use each system.

If you permanently need both then choose a one as a primary OS and use a VM such as VirtualBox for the other.